# Error trying to instantiate Word ApplicationClass

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ms-word, office-interop

When I add Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word in my references and using in my class I get some strange error and I am not able to solve it. I have attached a photo.

[image: in this image red rectangle is my problem]

It says:

> Interop type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass' cannot be embedded. Use the applicable interface instead.

How to resolve this?

Comment: Please add code/errors/stack trace as text, not image.

Answer (score 4):

Remove `Class` suffix, just use

```
Application applicationclass = new Application();
```

OR

Open assembly properties in VS and set "Embed Interop Types" to "False".

Comment: if i set "Embed Interop Types" to "False".then i get a new error on the web browser.

Answer (score 2):

You can't (or at least shouldn't) instantiate the class itself. You should ways use the interface. Okay, you can't create a new instance of an interface, but since the interface has the `CoClass` attribute on it, it can. Behind the scenes there is some magic going on.

So this code is fine, although it seems weird to create an instance of an interface:

```
Application application = new Application();
```

Also, you shouldn't use Office interop in ASP.NET, as per Microsofts guidelines in [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757).